# Is Firebase Crashlytics mixing data from version code increments sharing same version name?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

In android ecosystem, we operate with version name and version code notion while publishing particular app version: 1.1.1-123, where 1.1.1 is version name and 123 is version code. It almost looks as if Firebase Crashlytics combines crashes from two different version codes: 1.1.1-123 and 1.1.1-124. Is it Firebase Crashlytics bug or expected behavior? If the latter, why UI allows filtering not only by version name but also by version code?